# WCF Service Configuration for basicHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, basichttpbinding

I am having an issue where I have SOA with a web site consuming services and a web site hosting services.  One of my services accepts an image (byte[]).  When I pass an image of 83kb to the WCF service I get the following error:

*The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.*

There is no specific config in my server side configuration for this service.  The following is in my consuming web application web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISchoolSettings" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="998192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50977/Interface/Schools.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISchoolSettings" contract="Services.Schools.ISchoolSettings" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISchoolSettings" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It looks like .net is ignoring the fact I've set `MaxArrayLength=2147483647` for this binding configuration.

I am using `.net 4.0` here.  Curiously, I have a machine with `.net 4.5` on it and I DONT get this error on that machine!!

I've tried all sorts but cant seem to get around this issue.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your web.config from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you change the setting on both the client config and the service config. It can be a bit confusing sometimes to see where the exception is actually occurring.

Comment: As I dont have anything defined in the Server config, what should I be defining?

Comment: That means either you're configuring the service in code or your service is running with all the standard WCF defaults. If you're not configuring in code, take the entire `binding` element from the client and place it in the service config file. This will make your client & service be in-sync. You'll also need to configure the service to use this binding. [Here is the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354.aspx) for the `serviceModel` element but it's easier to create a WCF service from the Visual Studio template and use that to configure the service.